# Why Blender and git seems like working so well together?

Tags: blend-files, file-format, external-applications

Blender and git seems like working exceptionally well together!

I took some tests with hundred of megabyte files and versioned these several times.. the result was a git folder of just a couple of MB... and sometime even lighter then before committing!

from test to test I run a `git gc` for the garbage collection...

I also took some tests on merging and apparently It handles *(for simple tasks like materials modification and new objects creation/deletation)* the thing pretty well!

so my question is...

**how's that git works so well with Blender? Is something in the code? It's because of python... anything else?** =]

*tested with git 2.17.0-1 and blender 2.79.b-5*

Comment: Probably because git uses 'zip' to compress files...?

Comment: yes but dimensions are almost the same at every commit.. even if compressed, a bin should remain a bin and like so double or like so... the size of the repo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender saves a direct copy of its memory to the blend file. As a result, the file contents change little when you change a small thing in Blender. This allows tools that perform binary diffs (not sure about Git, but Subversion and Mercurial do a good job at this) to produce a small diff.

When you save your blend file compressed, the entire file can change even when in Blender only a single bit was flipped. This prevents efficient diffing, and thus makes it work much less efficient with such tools.